# How to compile poppler 0.45 to DLL for Qt5.5.1 on window

Tags: qt, cmake, mingw, qt5, poppler

I want to build DLL of poppler0.45 version for Qt5.5.1 on window. I follow to the guide on http://www.seppemagiels.com/blog/building-poppler-windows-using-mingw but not successful. I use CMake tool to compile library. The error below:
[image]

How to config the value correctly? or if have existed DLL for poppler 0.45, please share with me.

Comment: There is no error Qt5 is just not found.

Comment: Just set a QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE to a `qmake.exe` binary from your Qt version.

Comment: I just compiled it few days ago. It buy me a lot of times to compile it, your problem is still in the early step, there are a lot of issue after. If you want, you can take it from my github : https://github.com/apinprastya/pulas

Comment: @Apin: Thanks for your lib. I can use your DLL file to display PDF file. It save me a lot lot of time. Could you please share me the version of poppler which you build into DLL file? Is there any way to check poppler vesion from DLL file? And also, do you share the manual to build the DLL file

Comment: It is the latest one which is 0.45. Please check on google how to check dll version, there are a lot about it. And about the manual to build it, not sure if I can spare time to do it :)

Comment: @Apin Thank you very much. I understand

Comment: the github link not work can you please upload it again or give me a valid link thank you